# Chromecast built-in: how to interact with 3rd party receiver applications from hardware user interface perspective?

Tags: google-cast

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/audio) an audio hardware device with a physical user interface (buttons, knobs) that supports Chromecast built-in (aka Cast Audio Device) should interact with the receiver app to control playback

> Google Cast for audio devices may have their own playback controls (such as buttons, remotes). These use the media playback messages defined for the urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media namespace, as described in Media Playback Messages, to control playback on the receiver application. Your receiver application must support these media playback messages to support the device's playback controls.

There are no futher details however. Especially I wonder how the application layer on the audio device (think SoC controller logic) would interact with 3rd party receiver application. I assume that would have to be TPC/IP based http communication between the controller logic and the receiver API.

Imagine the following use case:

- user uses his smartphone and starts a cast enabled media player app of streaming service A.
- He starts playback of a playlist of streaming service A and hits the Cast button to play it on his Chromecast built-in audio device.
- The audio device takes over playback using A's receiver app and plays the track.
- Later, and still while the device plays the A playlist, the user walks to the device and presses the physical "next" button on the audio device to skip to next track in the playlist

Now by using what means would the apllication layer on the hardware device be able to control the A receiver app? According to the doc it should use the Media Playback Messages but then again how should the device know for example the mediaSessionId required to control a receiver?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is at most one session running on a Cast device at a time, theoretically speaking, there is no need for the hardware to know the sessionId. When a hardware device becomes a Cast device, there is a tight integration between various layers that are internal and receiver applications do not need to be involved in. The bottom line is that as long as a receiver application uses the standard SDK (hence, uses the standard urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media namespace), the right messages will flow to the receiver and the SDK will do the right thing; that is all that a developer of a receiver application needs to care about; anything beyond that is internal to the Cast device.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I assumed - from a receiver perspective it should not matter what the origin of the message is. My question was more about the integration on the hardware side, or is this also abstracted by the Chromecast built-in SDK?